# Use variable value for selecting which UI label to change

Tags: java, function, variables, object

Within the Java application UI, there are 10 labels with names:

```
mainLabel1
mainLabel2
...
mainLabel10
```

and a primitive variable (integer):

```
int x = 4;
```

Assume the 'x' value is changing through the execution of the application, thus the value is not known. At one point, the application is required to change visibility of one of the labels to true:

```
mainLabelX.setVisible(true);
```

**The question**
Is there an easy/simple solution of using the value of 'x' (example being 4), as the last part of the label name so that the call to setVisible looks like this:

```
mainLabelX.setVisible(True);
```

Can that value of 'x' variable be used as part of the label name? Currently, I am using a lot of if statements and it definitely doesn't feel like its the only/best solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In any case you have to check which Label fulfills the condition, therefore you need a `Map<Integer, Label>`:

```
Map<Integer, Label> labelMap = new HashMap<Integer, Label>():
...

Label l = map.get(x);
l.setVisible(true);
```

If you name all your Labels as: `mainLabel1`, `mainLabel2` you should add to them a field name, save them in a `List` and iterate over it to get the correct `List`:

```
List<Label> list = new ArrayList<>();

for(Label l: list){
   if(label.getName().equals("aName"))
   l.setVisible(true);
}
```

I do not consider the later an elegant solution though.

Comment: This seems to be the best (most accurate) answer so far. Thanks, I shall give this a go!

Answer (score 3):

You are getting confused between reference to your JLabels and the names of those labels. You can change the name of the labels dynamically at runtime - adding/appending whatever you want. But the references are totally different.

In your case you have 10 labels. So make an array of 10 JLabels.

```
    JLabel[] myLabels = new JLabel[10];
    int i = 0;
    for(JLabel label : myLabels) {
        label = new JLabel();
        label.setName("label" + i);  //here i can be dynamically changed at runtime
        i++;
    }
```

Just for clarification

```
mainLabelX.setVisible(True);
```

In above mainLabelX is not the label name but the name of reference that points to your JLabel object. As mentioned above you can use arrays for the same.

**Update:**

As per the above accepted answer I propose a slightly different solution.

Instead of maintaining a Map you can very well append your changing number to you labels. Note that the mapping is static which means if your number is 4 then the label with 4 in it must be visible. So you can iterate over the array of labels and set its visibility as per your design requirements whose name contain your number.

```
        if(label.getName().contains(String.valueOf(yourInteger))) {
            label.setVisible(true);
        }
```

My suggestion would be make a `final private prefix` for your label names. Then simply add numbers to it while creating labels.

```
    private final String labelPrefix = "label";
    for(JLabel label : myLabels) {
        label = new JLabel();
        label.setName(labelPrefix + i);
        i++;
    }
```

Comment: In this way he has to check for the correct name additionally, since the name of the reference has nothing to do with the field name.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I meant the actual reference, the name will never change, however I need to reference one of those labels, without knowing which precisely. Sorry for the unclear question!

Comment: @arjacsoh **name of the reference has nothing to do with the field name** I disagree. you can simply get and set the JLabel names at runtime by invoking getter/setter methods on the references. Though intention of OP was reference names but your statement is not true.

Comment: As you write it in your update it does the task correct. The OP wanted weirdly to call the method according to the name of the reference, which is anyway not elegant.

Comment: It was mostly a case of my curiosity as to whether such function/simple solution that remains elegant exists, as far as I am aware it does in C. I'm re-writing my application to eliminate the need for this anyway. Thanks to all for help.

Answer (score 1):

You could Use a `List<DefaultKeyValue>` or with Reflection you could call a getter or setter method for you Variable.

For reflection there are many examples how to use:
http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/index.html